# How to extract values from list at specific position

Tags: r, list

Supposed I have the following list:

```
x <- list(rbind(c(1,1,1,0),c(1,0,1,0), c(1,0,0,0)), c(1,1,0,1), c(1,2,3,4))
```

I know how to use `unlist(lapply(x, "[[", 4))`, but it works only when they are vectors inside the list.

If I want to extract the last column of each list, how can I do this ?

The return should be `c(0, 1, 4)`.

Thank you

Comment: The last column of the first list element is `c(0,0,0)` - why is it only 0 in your expected result?

Comment: @beginneR I forgot to mention when the last column of each component are the same, the unique one can be used.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this important detail.

Answer (score 0):

The second and third `list` elements are just `vectors`.  Also, your description of extracting the `last column` and expected result is confusing.  If you want to extract the last element.

```
 sapply(x,  function(.x) tail(c(.x),1))
 #[1] 0 1 4
```

Or you could convert the `vector` elements to `matrix` and then extract the `columns`.

```
  x1 <- lapply(x, function(.x) if(is.vector(.x)) t(.x) else (.x))
  x2 <- lapply(x1, `[`,,4)
  x2
  #[[1]]
  #[1] 0 0 0

  #[[2]]
  #[1] 1

  #[[3]]
  #[1] 4

   unique(unlist(x2))
   #[1] 0 1 4
```

Also, your code is only extracting the elements at specific positions and not the `columns`. For example:

```
  z <- list(matrix(c(1:6), ncol=3), matrix(c(1:12), ncol=4))
  lapply(z, `[[`, 3) #extracts the third element and not the third column
  #[[1]]
  #[1] 3

  #[[2]]
  #[1] 3
```

whereas,

```
   lapply(z, `[`, ,3)
  #[[1]]
  #[1] 5 6

  #[[2]]
  #[1] 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
unlist(lapply(x, function(y) if(is.vector(y)) y[length(y)] else unique(y[,ncol(y)])))
#[1] 0 1 4
```